# Java-ee remote calling ejb transaction from pojo

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions

I'm facing a problem calling an EJB (which persist entites) from a remote client via "Context lookup" and then doing different transactions. Each time I'm calling the statefull container managed EJB it commits and not rolling back in case of an error. My Pseudo-Code:

Calling the remote-EJB persist method:

```
transactionController.persist(getCurrentEntity());
```

Where transactionController was set via "Context lookup".

And my EJB:

```
@Remote

    @Stateful(name = "TransactionController")
    public class TransactionController {
        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager entityManager;

        public void persist(Object object){
            entityManager.persist(object);
        }
```

Is it possible managing transactions within the containter when calling it from a pojo (remote)? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling an ejb and want to manage the transaction( e.g rollback on exception). you can do explicit transaction management. which involves marking the transaction boundaries explicitly. [Explicit transaction management](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/ebeans/ch08_05.htm)

Comment: Yes, Bean managed transactions are supported, is there a solution for container managed transactions (without explicitly set "begin" and "commit")

Comment: begin and commit should be done in your _remote client_ if it is not an ejb.